# Unity Instantiating a variable through string

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need help instantiating a variable through a string. I need this for placing the right building based on the building number variable so I can make my code shorter and more readable than just doing many if statements.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class main : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text cashText;
    public static float cash = 0f;
    public float changeCash = 0f;
    public GameObject building1;
    public GameObject building2;
    public GameObject building3;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        cash = changeCash;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        cashText.text = "cash: " + cash.ToString();
        Application.targetFrameRate = 60;
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("r"))
        {
            Destroy(GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("building"));
            GameObject[] projectiles = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("projectile");
            foreach(GameObject projectilesfind in projectiles)
            {
                GameObject.Destroy(projectilesfind);
            }
            Instantiate("building" + menu.buildingNumber);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what "instanciating a variable through a string" means?

Comment: View the code at the bottom it shows that i am trying to instantiate one of the building variables that i have made at the top through make a string that is the same as the variable name by taking the building number from a different script.

Comment: you do **not** want to do this! Yes what you ask for is possible and called "reflection" but instead what you actually wouldrather want to do is have an array / enum etc and rather access the according `GameObject` by index

Comment: The `Instanciate` function creates a new `GameObject` in the scene. Did you mean you wanted to clone one of the three game objects variables based on that number?

Comment: @nirshahar I'd say it's clear that OP wants to do that yes ... but `The Instanciate function creates a new GameObject in the scene` pretty much depends on what you are using it for ;) This is not true for any asset type e.g.

Comment: derHugo can you please show me how to do this

Comment: Make a dictionary of objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said what you are asking for is possible, it is called ["reflection"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/reflection) and I would **strongly** recommend to **NOT** use this. Therefore I won't even tell you how to do it here. Use the link on own risk ;)

---

#### Array + index

I would rather use e.g. an array like

```
public GameObject[] buildings;
```

and then later do

```
// assuming 1-based User input but c# arrays are 0-based
Instantiate(buildings[menu.buildingNumber - 1]);
```

or if `menu.buildingNumber` is a `string` itself then do e.g.

```
if(int.TryParse(menu.buildingNumber, out var index))
{
    Instantiate(buildings[index - 1]);
}
```

---

#### Dictionary + Key

Or depending on your Input you could also use a Dictionary like

```
public GameObject building1;
public GameObject building2;
public GameObject building3;

private readonly Dictionary<string, GameObject> buildings = new Dictionary<string, GameObject>();

private void Awake()
{
    buildings[nameof(building1)] = building1;
    buildings[nameof(building2)] = building2;
    buildings[nameof(building3)] = building3;
}
```

then later you can do

```
if(buildings .TryGetValue("building" + menu.buildingNumber, out var building))
{
    Instantiate(building);
}
```

Note though that this is pretty error prone and you will have to rename your fields / the string in `TryGetValue` according to your needs all the time